# BlackBerry browserfield find and highlight text

Tags: java, javascript, blackberry, browserfield

I'm writing an application that includes a BrowserField that I am using to show a HTML file.  What I would like to do is show the user a dialog that they can type some text into and then find the text, highlight it and scroll it into view (like the native browser does).  Does anyone know how I can achieve this programmatically?  How does the native browser implement this functionality?  Do I need to execute some Javascript using browserfield.executescript or can this be implemented using methods on the browserfield?